# Bash variable resets in for loop (no pipe)

Tags: bash

I have trim down my code to this simple for loop. I don't understand why the counter tot_add is not cumulative but rather 1 all the time:

```
cd /path/to/my/workspace;
tot_add=0;
for d in ./*/;
do (cd "$d";
 let tot_add=tot_add+1;
 echo $tot_add;
) done
```

expected result:

```
1
2
3
```

actual result

```
1
1
1
```

I have read this answer about subshell with Pipe.

[BASH FAQ entry #24: "I set variables in a loop. Why do they suddenly disappear after the loop terminates? Or, why can't I pipe data to read?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)

However, I'm not using pipe character here.

Comment: You're using `(` ... `)`. That explicitly creates a subshell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`()` spawns a subshell.

So it being actually added in a subshell and when the subshell exits the parent shell does not have the resultant rather starts again from `0`, hence you are always getting 1.

To fix this behavior, get rid of the subshell.